# Channels in Golang

Tags: go

I am trying to implement a function that sends to another an undetermined number of variables (type float64) using a channel.

The second function will receive and create a slice respecting the order of reception.

This is an exercise to add one more function to a system that I already have developed. That is why the code is stated in this way.

When the buffer is 1, the program enters Deadlock. If I increase it to 7 (= slice length), the program runs wrong and does not stop.

I understand that the buffer should be equal to 0 or not greater than 1 to ensure that there is no loss of data and order.

https://play.golang.org/p/rnLH51GinsG

I hope you can help me.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var waitgroup sync.WaitGroup

/* This function simulates another that sends an
undetermined amount of float64.*/
func sendFloat64() <-chan float64 {
    channel := make(chan float64, 7) // Buffer = 1 to ensure receipt of the first data before sending the second
    defer close(channel)

    originalSlice := []float64{90, 180, 270, 300, 330, 358, 359} // It represents an undetermined number of values.

    for _, v := range originalSlice {
        channel <- v // one value at a time to keep order
        fmt.Println("SendFloat64: send data to channel", v)
    }
    return channel
}

/* This function receives the values and then it will be
incorporated in a slice respecting the order in which they were sent.*/
func RecreateSlice() <-chan []float64 {

    waitgroup.Add(1)
    defer waitgroup.Done()

    channelOut := make(chan []float64)
    defer close(channelOut)

    var slice []float64

    for {
        dataRecived, ok := <-sendFloat64()
        if !ok {
            break
        }
        fmt.Println("RecreateSlice: Data received from channel", dataRecived)

        slice = append(slice, dataRecived)

    }

    channelOut <- slice

    return channelOut
}

func main() {

    go RecreateSlice()
    PM := <-RecreateSlice()
    fmt.Println("Printed in main", PM)
    waitgroup.Wait()
}
```

Comment: `if !ok {
   break
  }` --- this condition is never `true`: you always request for a new non-empty channel, so `ok` is always `true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think this code is better. It also does guarantee the order.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

// sendFloat64 simulates another that sends an
// undetermined amount of float64.
func sendFloat64(ch chan<- float64) {
    originalSlice := []float64{90, 180, 270, 300, 330, 358, 359}
    for _, v := range originalSlice {
        // send the data in order as soon as possible to the reciver
        ch <- v
        fmt.Println("SendFloat64: send data to channel", v)
    }
    close(ch)
}

// RecreateSlice receives the values and then it will be
// incorporated in a slice respecting the order in which they were sent.
func RecreateSlice() []float64 {
    var stream []float64
    // Create a float64 channel with a buffer of 1
    channel := make(chan float64, 1)
    go sendFloat64(channel)
    // Append data until the channel is closed
    for data := range channel {
        fmt.Println("RecreateSlice: Data received from channel", data)
        stream = append(stream, data)
    }
    return stream
}

func main() {
    result := RecreateSlice()
    fmt.Println("MainSlice: ", result)
}
```

Output:

```
RecreateSlice: Data received from channel 90
SendFloat64: send data to channel 90
SendFloat64: send data to channel 180
SendFloat64: send data to channel 270
RecreateSlice: Data received from channel 180
RecreateSlice: Data received from channel 270
RecreateSlice: Data received from channel 300
SendFloat64: send data to channel 300
SendFloat64: send data to channel 330
SendFloat64: send data to channel 358
RecreateSlice: Data received from channel 330
RecreateSlice: Data received from channel 358
RecreateSlice: Data received from channel 359
SendFloat64: send data to channel 359
MainSlice:  [90 180 270 300 330 358 359]
```

- Notice the order for SendFloat64:

```
90, 180, 270, 300, 330, 358, 359
```

- Notice the order for RecreateSlice:

```
90, 180, 270, 300, 330, 358, 359
```

And the slice returned by RecreateSlice is in order (verification)

You can extend your solution based on the idea of this code. I've tried to comment parts of the code so that you can understand.

Comment: It is what I needed. I will study the code to learn. Thank you very much!!